# HTML and CSS: using background image as a clickable link

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use a html and css trick to give the impression of using a background image as a clickable link following this [tutorial](http://ran.ge/2009/11/11/css-trick-turning-a-background-image-into-a-clickable-link/). I can't get to work, however, due to two issues:

1) The link is not filling the space of the background image

2) The link will not move off the screen

I'm using an html code integration block for a weebly website. I'm a beginner to html and CSS.

```
<a href="website.net/link" title="photo" id=«photo»>photo</a>

<a class="photo"></a>

<style type="text/css">

.photo {
    background-image: url(myImageLink.jpg);
    background-size: 300px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-clip: border-box;
    transition: background-size 0.2s;
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.07,1.41,.82,1.41);

    display: block;
    width: 190px;
    height: 190px;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-indent: 100%;
    white-space:nowrap;
}

.photo:hover {
    background-size: 500px;
}

</style>
```

Comment: href- hyper link is missing in photo class name

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/o9ewvunh/)**

You need a single `<a>` tag, style a background to it, give required href to it and make it `display: block`

html

```
<a class="photo" href="website.net/link" title="photo" id="photo">photo</a>
```

css

```
.photo {
    background-image: url('http://www.thinksnaps.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/images-background.jpg');
    background-size: 300px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-clip: border-box;
    transition: background-size 0.2s;
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.07,1.41,.82,1.41);

    display: block;
    width: 190px;
    height: 190px;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-indent: 100%;
    white-space:nowrap;
}

.photo:hover {
    background-size: 500px;
}
```

Comment: Works for **IE, Chrome, Firexof** ? _Opera, Safari_ ? works using ***another image for hover*** ?

Answer (score 3):

check your html code it should be like this

```
<a class="photo" href="website.net/link" title="photo" id="photo">photo</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

Another example how to use .svg images as clickable background. Note that the text on links is hidden by css but may be shown along with clickable .svg images after the text. If you need the images displayed before the text just change ::after pseudo-element for ::before in the snippet below.

**UPD:** Added material design Google font icons as a clickable background example.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Clickable background</title>
  <!-- Citation from http://google.github.io/material-design-icons/#setup-method-1-using-via-google-web-fonts
  Similar to other Google Web Fonts, the correct CSS will be served to
  activate the 'Material Icons' font specific to the browser. An additional CSS
  class will be declared called .material-icons. Any element that uses this
  class will have the correct CSS to render these icons from the web font. -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  
  <style type="text/css" media="screen">
  /* Make clickable text on links invisible. */
  .clickable-background {
    font-size:0;
  }

  .clickable-background:hover ::after, .clickable-background ::after {
    content: '';
    display:inline-block;
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
  /*
  The default clickable background image (mouse for PC) to display if no
  background image is defined or it is crippled or not reachable. See the
  `fill="rgb(255, 0, 0)"' key=value, this is the color (red) of the .svg image.
  The width and height are defined above, so no need to change them in the source.
  All the images are taken from: https://materialdesignicons.com/
  */
    background: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="24" height="24" fill="rgb(255, 0, 0)" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M11,1.07C7.05,1.56 4,4.92 4,9H11M4,15A8,8 0 0,0 12,23A8,8 0 0,0 20,15V11H4M13,1.07V9H20C20,4.92 16.94,1.56 13,1.07Z" /></svg>');
  }

  /* Every image need to have its own rule defined. */
  .stackoverflow-icon ::after{
    background: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="24" height="24" fill="grey" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M17.36,20.2V14.82H19.15V22H3V14.82H4.8V20.2H17.36M6.77,14.32L7.14,12.56L15.93,14.41L15.56,16.17L6.77,14.32M7.93,10.11L8.69,8.5L16.83,12.28L16.07,13.9L7.93,10.11M10.19,6.12L11.34,4.74L18.24,10.5L17.09,11.87L10.19,6.12M14.64,1.87L20,9.08L18.56,10.15L13.2,2.94L14.64,1.87M6.59,18.41V16.61H15.57V18.41H6.59Z" /></svg>');
  }

  /*
  The source of images is used instead of image files for the need to change
  the color (and may be other svg values) on hover event. It seems a bit redundant
  to duplicate the whole image source just for the case, but only foreground
  .images can be changed in color with css `fill' property. Let us know if you
  discover simpler way to do it. Otherwise you need to edit .svg file before using
  it as a downloadable resourse which is the same what we do here.
  See more reasons why the source of the .svg image is better than the link to it:
  https://css-tricks.com/probably-dont-base64-svg/
  */
  .stackoverflow-icon:hover ::after {
    background: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="24" height="24" fill="blue" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M17.36,20.2V14.82H19.15V22H3V14.82H4.8V20.2H17.36M6.77,14.32L7.14,12.56L15.93,14.41L15.56,16.17L6.77,14.32M7.93,10.11L8.69,8.5L16.83,12.28L16.07,13.9L7.93,10.11M10.19,6.12L11.34,4.74L18.24,10.5L17.09,11.87L10.19,6.12M14.64,1.87L20,9.08L18.56,10.15L13.2,2.94L14.64,1.87M6.59,18.41V16.61H15.57V18.41H6.59Z" /></svg>');
  }

  .github-icon ::after{
    background: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="24" height="24" fill="grey" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M12,2A10,10 0 0,0 2,12C2,16.42 4.87,20.17 8.84,21.5C9.34,21.58 9.5,21.27 9.5,21C9.5,20.77 9.5,20.14 9.5,19.31C6.73,19.91 6.14,17.97 6.14,17.97C5.68,16.81 5.03,16.5 5.03,16.5C4.12,15.88 5.1,15.9 5.1,15.9C6.1,15.97 6.63,16.93 6.63,16.93C7.5,18.45 8.97,18 9.54,17.76C9.63,17.11 9.89,16.67 10.17,16.42C7.95,16.17 5.62,15.31 5.62,11.5C5.62,10.39 6,9.5 6.65,8.79C6.55,8.54 6.2,7.5 6.75,6.15C6.75,6.15 7.59,5.88 9.5,7.17C10.29,6.95 11.15,6.84 12,6.84C12.85,6.84 13.71,6.95 14.5,7.17C16.41,5.88 17.25,6.15 17.25,6.15C17.8,7.5 17.45,8.54 17.35,8.79C18,9.5 18.38,10.39 18.38,11.5C18.38,15.32 16.04,16.16 13.81,16.41C14.17,16.72 14.5,17.33 14.5,18.26C14.5,19.6 14.5,20.68 14.5,21C14.5,21.27 14.66,21.59 15.17,21.5C19.14,20.16 22,16.42 22,12A10,10 0 0,0 12,2Z" /></svg>');
  }

  .github-icon:hover ::after {
    background: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="24" height="24" fill="blue" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M12,2A10,10 0 0,0 2,12C2,16.42 4.87,20.17 8.84,21.5C9.34,21.58 9.5,21.27 9.5,21C9.5,20.77 9.5,20.14 9.5,19.31C6.73,19.91 6.14,17.97 6.14,17.97C5.68,16.81 5.03,16.5 5.03,16.5C4.12,15.88 5.1,15.9 5.1,15.9C6.1,15.97 6.63,16.93 6.63,16.93C7.5,18.45 8.97,18 9.54,17.76C9.63,17.11 9.89,16.67 10.17,16.42C7.95,16.17 5.62,15.31 5.62,11.5C5.62,10.39 6,9.5 6.65,8.79C6.55,8.54 6.2,7.5 6.75,6.15C6.75,6.15 7.59,5.88 9.5,7.17C10.29,6.95 11.15,6.84 12,6.84C12.85,6.84 13.71,6.95 14.5,7.17C16.41,5.88 17.25,6.15 17.25,6.15C17.8,7.5 17.45,8.54 17.35,8.79C18,9.5 18.38,10.39 18.38,11.5C18.38,15.32 16.04,16.16 13.81,16.41C14.17,16.72 14.5,17.33 14.5,18.26C14.5,19.6 14.5,20.68 14.5,21C14.5,21.27 14.66,21.59 15.17,21.5C19.14,20.16 22,16.42 22,12A10,10 0 0,0 12,2Z" /></svg>');
  }

  /* This rule MUST to be placed under all clickable background rules.*/
  .clickable-background:hover ::after, .clickable-background ::after{
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
  }

/*******************************************************************************
Even better solution: clickable  Google font material icons expessed as ligatures.
See the <link> tag above.
*******************************************************************************/
  /* Make clickable text on links invisible. */
  .material-icons {
    font-size:0;
  }
  .material-icons a {
    text-decoration: none;
  } 
  .material-icons ::after {
    font-size: 48px;
    color: grey;
  /*
  The default clickable background image (crossed phone) to display if no
  background image is defined or it is crippled or not reachable.
  */
    content: 'phonelink_erase';
  }
  .material-icons:hover ::after {
    color: blue;
  }
  
  /* Each clickable font icon need its own rule with the name of a ligature as content property value */
  .material-icons.clickable-home ::after {
    content: 'home';
  }
  .material-icons.clickable-thumb_up ::after {
    content: 'thumb_up';
  }
  .material-icons.clickable-android ::after {
    content: 'android';
  }
  .material-icons.clickable-important_devices ::after {
    content: 'important_devices';
  }
  .material-icons.clickable-import_contacts ::after {
    content: 'import_contacts';
  }
  .material-icons.clickable-phonelink_setup ::after {
    content: 'phonelink_setup';
  }
  </style>

</head>
<body>
  <p>Note that links below do not lead you to the sites linked because in the code snippet the default behaviour of links is disabled by stackoverflow.com. See the browser status bar and cursor type when hover over links. For actual testing just copy the whole snippet and create your own test.html file.</p>
  <span class="clickable-background stackoverflow-icon">
    <a href="http://stackoverflow.com" title="Stackoverflow" target="_blank">Stackoverflow - sounds good, but the icon is better.</a>
  </span>
  <span class="clickable-background github-icon">
    <a href="https://github.com/" title="Github" target="_blank">Github - sounds good, but the icon is better.</a>
  </span>
  <p>May be even better solution is to use clickable font symbols. Read more about this cool feature on the links below.</p>
  </span>
  <span class="material-icons clickable-home">
    <a href="http://google.github.io/material-design-icons/" title="Material design icons" target="_blank">Material design icons</a>
  </span>
  <span class="material-icons clickable-thumb_up">
    <a href="https://design.google.com/icons/" title="Download material icons" target="_blank">Download material icons</a>
  </span>  
  
  <span class="material-icons clickable-android">
    <a href="https://developers.google.com/fonts/" title="Google fonts" target="_blank">Google fonts</a>
  </span>
  <span class="material-icons clickable-important_devices">
    <a href="http://alistapart.com/article/the-era-of-symbol-fonts/" title="Symbol fonts" target="_blank">The Era of Symbol Fonts</a>
  </span>
  <span class="material-icons clickable-import_contacts">
    <a href="https://material.google.com/style/icons.html" title="Material icons' geometric shapes" target="_blank">Material icons' geometric shapes</a>
  </span>
  <span class="material-icons clickable-phonelink_setup">
    <a href="https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/blob/master/iconfont/codepoints/" title="Code points reference" target="_blank">Code points reference</a>
  </span>
</body>
</html>
```