# how to make background image responsive

Tags: html, css

How to make background image responsive using bootstrap? I am trying to set a mobile device image as background image   and then add text and buttons over it to make it look as working phone but then it is not responsive.. and if I am directly using image it is responsive but in that case I am unable to add text and buttons over it. So help in either way.

Comment: via css: background:cover;

Comment: Did you check the html/css solution from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25422241/html-and-css-using-background-image-as-a-clickable-link which together with @wander's hint to use `background:cover` should get you going, shouldn't it?

Comment: I had already gone through this but background cover option is not working. Is there any other way to make background image responsive or to put buttons or images over the <img src="..."> tag.